# Is there a package that allows online updating of glm with new data?

Tags: r, glm

Is there a package that allows updating of a logistic regression with new data, without retraining the model on all data points again?

i.e. say I have fitted a model `glm(y~., data=X)`. Then some time later I receive more data (more rows) `Y`. I need a model that trains on `rbind(X,Y)`. But instead of re-training the model on this new combined dataset, it would be good if the model can simply update itself using `Y` (either using bayesian or frequentist method).

The reason I am seeking an update method is that over time, the dataset will grow to be huge, so the re-training method will become increasing computationally infeasible.

Comment: If you were fitting a least-squares regression model, then you could probably do this. But for logistic regression, or any other GLM, I don't think there are any computational shortcuts to refitting on everything

Comment: One thing you could probably do is refit, but use the current parameter estimates as the starting point

Comment: Sounds like a Bayesian issue to me. Have you had a look at the brms package? It has a gazillion dependencies, but it does claim to fit Bayesian generalized (non-)linear multivariate multilevel models using 'Stan' for full Bayesian inference. And there is an update method that may be what you want. Not tested though. ;)